# How can I filter record by start time / end time in mysql + codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

The table structure is like that

```
start_time TimeStamp null
end_time TimeStamp null
```

The problem is ,  I would like to get all record within the start time and endtime, **and** all the value that has null start time & end time value (that means the record is not restrict by time)

```
  $this->db->where('start_date <=', now());
        $this->db->where('end_date >', now());
```

tried some sql for the first requirement but no luck , thanks for helping

Comment: How could start and end be both now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like the query logic you need would go something like this:

```
...
WHERE NOW() BETWEEN start_date AND end_date
    OR (start_date IS NULL AND end_date IS NULL)
```

To do this with [Codeigniter's Active Record](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html), try:

```
$this->db->where('NOW() BETWEEN start_date AND end_date');
$this->db->or_where('start_date IS NULL AND end_date IS NULL');
```

Alternatively, you could put the whole thing into one statement:

```
$where = 'NOW() BETWEEN start_date AND end_date OR (start_date IS NULL AND end_date IS NULL)';
$this->db->where($where);
```

Answer (score 2):

You would probably need to have a compound query.

```
$within_range = array('start_date <=' => now(), 'end_date =>' => now());
$not_restricted = array('start_date IS NULL' => null, 'end_date IS NOT NULL' => null)
$this->db->where($within_range)->or_where($not_restricted);
```

see more about the associative array and or_where syntax at https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#select

of course you can query using raw sql:

```
$this->db->select('select ...');
```